# Can I use Videoview and Imageview at same time in Android 5.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-imageview, android-videoview

My device runs android 5.1 and I need to use Imageview and videoview same time. Will android 5.1 support that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can both work together given that the 5.1 is greater than or equal to the minimum api specifications. 
you can always use `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)` on the onCreate method declaration.

Comment: Okay I will try that....Currently the problem is when app tries to runs two videos in videoview, The mediaplayer is crashing...This can be solved by above ?